# how can i change my print function in Singly linked?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to data structures in python. i just started them past few weeks. i strucked with some code in python. 
here is the code.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.data=value;
        self.next=None;

class SinglyLinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head=None
        self.tail=None

    def display_List(head):
        if head is not None:
            print(head.data)
            display_List(head.next)

    def insert_in_beginning(self,value):
        temp=Node(value)
        temp.next=self.head;
        self.head=temp;

    def insert_at_end(self,value):
        temp=Node(value)
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = temp;
        else:
            self.tail.next=temp;
        self.tail=temp

    def create_List(self):
        n=int(input("enter no of nodes"));
        if n==0:
            return;
        for i in range(n):
            value = int(input("enter element to be inserted"));
            self.insert_at_end(value)
list=SinglyLinkedList()
list.create_List()

option = int(input(" Enter your choice:"))

if option == 1:
    list.display_List(list.head)
elif option ==2:
    value= int(input("enter element to be inserted: "))
    list.insert_in_beginning(value);
elif option ==3:
    value= int(input("enter element to be inserted: "))
    list.insert_at_end(value);
```

every thing is working fine except display_List function. I want to print the elements using recurssion way. I messed up some where.
but the code snippet is same and i changed the display_List to following function it is working good. i want to change it to recursive way.

```
def display_List(self):
    if self.head is None:
        print("List is empty")
        return
    else:
        print("List is:",end=" ");
        p=self.head
        while p is not None:
            print(p.data,end=" ")
            p=p.next;


if option == 1:
    list.display_List()
```

this function is working fine insteed of recursive. can someone please help me to correct this code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call this function with class object.
You defined it befor , here:
Do not use 'list' use other as 'l' , list is keyword.

```
l=SinglyLinkedList()
```

Must called function like:

```
l.display_List(head.next)
```

So your function will be like this:

```
class Node: 
    def __init__(self,value): 
        self.data=value
        self.next=None 

class SinglyLinkedList: 
    def __init__(self): 
        self.head=None 
        self.tail=None 

    def display_List(self,head): 
        if head is not None: 
        print(head.data) 
        l.display_List(head.next) 

    def insert_in_beginning(self,value): 
        temp=Node(value) 
        temp.next=self.head
        self.head=temp 

    def insert_at_end(self,value): 
        temp=Node(value) 
        if self.head is None: 
            self.head = temp 
        else: 
            self.tail.next=temp 
        self.tail=temp 

    def create_List(self): 
        n=int(input("enter no of nodes"))
        if n==0: 
            return 
        for i in range(n): 
            value = int(input("enter element to be inserted")) 
            self.insert_at_end(value) 

l=SinglyLinkedList() 
l.create_List() 

option = int(input(" Enter your choice:")) 

if option == 1: 
    l.display_List(l.head) 

elif option ==2: 
    value= int(input("enter element to be inserted: ")) 
    l.insert_in_beginning(value) 

elif option ==3: 
    value= int(input("enter element to be inserted: ")) 
    l.insert_at_end(value)
```

´

I tested this code , it work well, without any problem.

Comment: NameError: name 'head' is not defined

Comment: Add self as argument of display_List: ` def display_List(self,head):´